# solve following contractor's problem

Tags: probability, economics

solve following contractor's problem.

(a) A contractor is building an office complex and needs to plan for water and electricity
demand(sizes of pipes, conduit, and wires). After consulting with prospective tenants
and examining historical data, the contractor decides that the demand for electricity
will range somewhere between 1 million and 150 million kilowatt-hours per day and
water demand will be between 4 and 200(in thousands of gallons per day). All combinations
of electrical and water demand are considered possible. Draw the sample space
of this experiment. And express the sample space as the set of ordered pairs(x: demand
for water, y: demand for electricity)

(b) Suppose that the probability is distributed uniformly (proportional to the area). And
let’s define water demand more than 100 high demand in water and electricity demand
more and 115 high demand in electricity. What is the probability of high demand in
water, high demand in electricity, high demand in both water and electricity?

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand the concept but I am having a difficult time with mathematical notations. For instance, (a) draw sample space of this experiment? is it just a 2-d field with the x-axis and y-axis( 4<x<200 and 1<y<150)? What would I need to put inside of the field?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I don't really see the point except to show the space is the range of elec times the range in water